# android: custom listview with checkbox, how to fill it

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, cursor, adapter

i have a listview filled by a cursor database, and with a custom xml for the row.
all works well, but i need to check or uncheck a checkbox in my row, dependig of the value in the db.
i don't know how.

this is my class:

```
    // inserisco gli elementi
    db.open();
    Cursor prendi_preventivi=db.prendi_preventivi();
    while(prendi_preventivi.moveToNext()){
        String nome_preventivo=prendi_preventivi.getString(prendi_preventivi.getColumnIndex("nome"));
        String data_preventivo=prendi_preventivi.getString(prendi_preventivi.getColumnIndex("data"));
        int approvato_preventivo=Integer.parseInt(prendi_preventivi.getString(prendi_preventivi.getColumnIndex("approvato")));
        preventiviLista.add(new Preventivo_per_lista(nome_preventivo,data_preventivo,approvato_preventivo));
    }
    db.close();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> data=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    for(int i=0;i<preventiviLista.size();i++){
        Preventivo_per_lista p=preventiviLista.get(i);
        HashMap<String,Object> preventivoMap=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        preventivoMap.put("nome", p.getNome());
        preventivoMap.put("data", p.getData());
        data.add(preventivoMap);
    }
    String[] from={"nome","data"};
    int[] to={R.id.nome_preventivo,R.id.data_preventivo};
    SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),data,R.layout.elemento_preventivo,from,to);
    lista_preventivi.setAdapter(adapter);
    lista_preventivi.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        // click di elemento
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long _id){
            System.out.println(lista_preventivi.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        }
    });
```

this is my Preventivo_per_lista:

```
public class Preventivo_per_lista{
private String nome;
private String data;
private int approvato;
public Preventivo_per_lista(String name,String data,int approvato){
        super();
        this.nome=name;
        this.data=data;
        this.approvato=approvato;
}
public String getNome(){
        return nome;
}
public String getData(){
    return data;
}
public int getApprovato(){
    return approvato;
}
}
```

this is my personal xml for the row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dip"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/elemento_preventivo"
android:weightSum="3">
<TextView android:id="@+id/nome_preventivo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/data_preventivo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/check_preventivo"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

if my approvato_preventivo is 1, i need to check the checkbox, if it is 0 i need to leave it like normal.

Can someone help me?

Comment: HI. SimpleAdapter is called "Simple" because it is really simple. Actually you can extend it and "invent" something but it is not good idea. Please use CursorAdapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html for your needs.

Comment: no it's not this the problem

Comment: No it is. CursorAdapter is basic approach for your task. It is much better from architecture and performance point of view. Give it a try. Currently you are inventing a "hook, how to use SimpleAdapter for the purpose it is not appropriate for".

Comment: ok, but this is not an answer to my question (already solved)

Comment: Sure it is not, that's why I placed it in comment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've solved it by myself:

this was the edited part:

```
    for(int i=0;i<preventiviLista.size();i++){
        Preventivo_per_lista p=preventiviLista.get(i);
        HashMap<String,Object> preventivoMap=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        preventivoMap.put("nome", p.getNome());
        preventivoMap.put("data", p.getData());
        if(p.getApprovato()==1){
            preventivoMap.put("approvato",true);
        }else{
            preventivoMap.put("approvato",false);
        }
        data.add(preventivoMap);
    }
    String[] from={"nome","data","approvato"};
    int[] to={R.id.nome_preventivo,R.id.data_preventivo,R.id.check_preventivo};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your getView() method of your adapter you need to have some check like this

```
if the "approvato_preventivo" is value type

if(approvato_preventivo==1)
{
    checkbox.setchecked(true);
}

else if(approvato_preventivo==0)
{
    checkbox.setchecked(false);
}
```

hope this will help

Comment: farrukh, that may be helpfull for you: 

all you wrote can be written like:
checkbox.setChecked(approvato_preventivo==1);