# Customlistview Checkbox issue while scrolling?

Tags: android

Hi I am Android Developer .Herewith i have mention my code.I have added check box in custom list view i am using Base Adapter .**While selected check-box that item only selected very nice but while scrolling after selected check-box went to unchecked automatically** .How to make solved this issue.Please give me solution for me .

```
class LabOrderListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ViewHolder holder;
    Boolean checkboxstate[];
    Context context;

    // DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    public LabOrderListAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        checkboxstate=new Boolean[observationDetailsList.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<checkboxstate.length;i++)
        checkboxstate[i]=false;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {

        if (observationDetailsList != null) {

            Log.i(this.toString(), "observationDetailsList"+observationDetailsList.size());

            return observationDetailsList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.lab_order_listitem, null);
        }
        if (v != null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txt_Order_code = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.orderingcode);
            holder.txt_ProcedureCode = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.procedurecode);
            holder.txt_Laboratory = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.Laboratory);
            holder.billtypeButton = (AprimaButton) v.findViewById(R.id.billtype);
            holder.txt_Order_Description = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.txt_Date = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.collectionDate);
            holder.orderCheckBox = (CheckBox) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkboxorder);

            holder.txt_TrackingNumber = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.accession);


            if(checkboxstate[position]==null){
                checkboxstate[position]=false;
            }
            if(observationDetailsList.get(position).GenerateLabOrder.equalsIgnoreCase("Flase"))
            {
                holder.orderCheckBox.setChecked(checkboxstate[position]);
            }

            if (observationDetailsList.get(position).GenerateLabOrder
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("False")) 
            {
                holder.orderCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                            if (checkboxstate[position] = true)
                            {

                                      patientOrderList.add(orderDetailsList.get(position));
                                      patientObservationList.add(observationDetailsList.get(position));



                            }

                            else{
                                if (checkboxstate[position] = false)
                                {
                                        checkboxstate[position]=false;
                                        patientOrderList.remove(orderDetailsList.get(position));
                                        patientObservationList.remove(observationDetailsList.get(position));
                                }

                            }


                        }
                    }
                });     

            }    
            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        return v;
    }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168814/how-to-change-the-text-of-a-checkbox-in-listview/17169411#17169411. check this example source https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/No0LrgJ6q2M

Comment: for that you have to make a boolean type array in your adapter having length same as your views, then put the value true on the position which checkbox is checked and place a check in get view mwthod which will varify checked from that array which you have created

Comment: or check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489559/android-custom-listview-with-checkbox-how-to-fill-it/17489792#17489792

Comment: i had the same problem. Go through the following link it will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248940/check-box-in-listview-not-working-properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a Model for storing the checked information of ListItem.
on getView() method you need to get the value from Model class for each item.

The smiler example are given in this [Blog](http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-checkbox-and.html/%22CustomListWithCheckBox%22)